# Android app with SQLite and the updates

Tags: android, sqlite, updates

I've a android app working with SQLite on the Google Play market. I want to make a new update to the app. If I upload the new apk file with the updates, when the users download that update, those the SQLite database is going to be erased and created again?. The updates are only for graphic interface and logic, nothing to do with the database, I didn't change it.

Comment: to localized ... since we don't know nothing about how your db is initalized ... maybe it depends on (i don't know) Version in Manifest file ...

Answer (score 1):

They will remain there. All the preferences and the database will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

The Android system doesn't mess with your data directory; it is your app's responsibility to create and update any files therein.

If you are using `SQLiteOpenHelper` and have increased the database version number, your `onUpgrade` function will be called.

Comment: Your Database wont be erased until you increase your version number In the database helper file .increasing  your apps version no will not affect  your database .